# Server not submitting form when posting a request - Python

Tags: python, post, python-requests

I am having a problem getting a response from a webserver when posting a request. The webserver is NanoDLP and I am trying to write a script that will load a file for 3D printing when I submit the form. Spent hours reading forums and "posts" that cover the topic and I cannot see what am doing wrong. Can someone please take a look and see if they can help me? Code is as follows:

```
import requests

machineAddr = "http://192.168.0.234"

# Get printable files from USB
urlUSBFiles = machineAddr + "/json/usb"
usbFiles = requests.get(urlUSBFiles).json()
print(usbFiles)

fileUploadName = input('What do you want to name your file?')
fileUploadData = {
        'USBfile': usbFiles[1],
        'Path': fileUploadName,
        'ProfileID': '3',
        'AutoCenter': '0',
        'StopLayers': '',
        'LowQualityLayerNumber': '0',
        'MaskFile': '',
        'MaskEffect': '',
        'ImageRotate': '0'
}

print(fileUploadData)

urlAddUSBFiles = machineAddr + "/plate/add-usb"
r = requests.post(urlAddUSBFiles, data=fileUploadData)
print(r)
```

Here is the response when the code is run:

```
['/media/usb0/DriveSleeve.stl', '/media/usb0/TestCube100um.zip']
```

`What do you want to name your file?turbo
{'USBfile': '/media/usb0/TestCube100um.zip', 'Path': 'turbo', 'ProfileID': '3', 'AutoCenter': '0', 'StopLayers': '', 'LowQualityLayerNumber': '0', 'MaskFile': '', 'MaskEffect': '', 'ImageRotate': '0'}
<Response [200]>
Process finished with exit code 0`

Thanks,

Dylan

Comment: To call the POST web service, you need to use requests.post method rather than get.

Comment: @notionquest Yes, that is done at the bottom of the code. The first part reads the contents of a USB drive - that is working perfectly. The second last line is what is giving me the problem.

Comment: What is the error message? Can you show the error message? What http status code (i.e. 400, 500 etc.) are you getting?

Comment: @notionquest, I have added it above.

Comment: But what do you expect to happen? The response code you are getting is 200 OK.

Comment: Hi, you need to take the data from the response "r" ( E.g. r.json()) or process the Response in any way.

Comment: This piece of code is supposed to fetch a list of files available on a flash drive, ask me to rename the file I want and then submit that data in a form to the sebserver to upload the file. As above, I get a 200 response, but when I check to see that the file is uploaded on the webserver, I can't see it. The funny thing is that if I do it on the webserver side and I inspect the network traffic I see a 302 response from the webserver. Something is off.

Comment: @Vall0n, could you elaborate please? Are you saying that I need to call the resulting page after making the post request in order to complete the request?

Comment: @Dylan144GT No, your python code looks just fine. I assume that there is a problem with the post request or the post content. Try to set the header "Content-Type:multipart/form-data".  And maybe you should analyze the requests while doing this via the ui.

Comment: @Vall0n, thanks for your response. I think you are right, there is a problem with the form data, I have been tending toward this being the issue since taking a break from behind the PC. I have a feeling setting the header content to what you suggest is going to go a long way toward fixing this issue. I will report back once I have tried it out. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For completeness sake, I found my issue. I was not defining the upload data as a dict, so the fix is:

```
fileUploadData = dict(
    USBfile = usbFiles[1],
    Path = fileUploadName,
    ProfileID = 3,
    AutoCenter = 0,
    StopLayers = '',
    LowQualityLayerNumber: 0,
    MaskFile = '',
    MaskEffect = '',
    ImageRotate = 0
)
```

I hope this helps someone else with similar issues! :)